# Subclassing UIButton and setting fontSize

Tags: ios

i am subclassing UIButton to set some defaults for the app, but i for some reason i am not able to change the font size.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // id button, set defaults
        [self setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40.0]];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I can change the color and the other propertise, but not the fontsize, it has no effect?

```
    idButton *LButton = [idButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [LButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    LButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, buttonY+(buttonHeight/2), screenWidth, buttonHeight);
    [self addSubview:LButton];
```

Comment: Try calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]` after you change the property.

Comment: Are you calling the initWithFrame button, or is it being instantiated with another init function, like from storyboard (initWithCoder)

Comment: i am using mySubClass *Button = [mySubClass buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; Setting a title and adding it as a subview in another view

Comment: Or are you using `buttonWithType:`?

Comment: buttonWithType is used yes

Comment: Put a break point in that line and see if your code reaches this line.

Comment: It does, since it applies the other propertise to the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that UIButton's method `setTitle:forState:` will reset the font back to the default.

One solution would be to override this method to use the NSAttributedString.  This will also allow you to set other attributes:

```
- (void) setTitle:(NSString *)customTitle forState:(UIControlState)state {
    if (customTitle) {
        NSMutableAttributedString *mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:customTitle];
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [customTitle length]);

        [mas addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                    value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40.0]
                    range:range];

        [mas addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                    value:@(1.1)
                    range:range];

        [self setAttributedTitle:mas forState:state];
    } else {
        [super setTitle:customTitle forState:state];
    }
}
```

Comment: it is incorrect to replace setTitle with setAttributedTitle

Comment: What do you mean it's incorrect?

Comment: by setting attributed title you disable all other changes you made to this button including alignment, text color and etc. In the same time you use both `setTitle` and `setAttributedTitle` - what happens when they are both set?

Answer (score 0):

oh dear we are in a pickle...

are you using a xib or storyboard.

If so then `initWithFrame:` doesn't get called

try `awakeFromNib`

or `initWithCoder:`

Comment: It does get called, since the other propertise are added! :) i added the init :)

Comment: try overwriting the setTitle:forState: be sure to call super first. Change the font in this method.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) for `+[UIButton buttonWithType]`.

`buttonWithType:` won't return instances of `UIButton` subclasses (such as your `LButton`).

Given you're setting the font in the `initWithFrame` method, you should call `[[LButton alloc] initWithFrame:]` instead:

```
idButton *LButton = [[LButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

I explained how to do this, [inside this post.](http://bit.ly/howToCustomizeButton) You're looking for `self.titleLabel.font.pointSize`. You can do this also with `UILabel` extensions but have to use `self.font.pointSize`.

If you have to support more than one language, you could also include an additional method where you check the language code, and change the `UIFont` based on this.

You just have to set the `UIFont` inside `awakeFromNib` with:

```
[self.titleLabel setFont:
  [UIFont fontWithName:kFont size:self.titleLabel.font.pointSize]];
```

to get the specific font.

```
- (UIFont *)whichFontShouldBeUsed{

    UIFont *fontToUse = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontBold 
                                        size:self.titleLabel.font.pointSize];

    if( [_language isEqualToString:@"tr"] &&
        [_language isEqualToString:@"pl"] ){

        fontToUse = [UIFont fontWithName:FOO 
                                    size:self.titleLabel.font.pointSize];
    }
    return fontToUse;
}
```